# Mostrar un botón hasta que le haga clic y guardar en localstorage

Tags: javascript

Quiero hacer que al hacer clic en un `input` que se muestra al hacer clic en un boton, este (el botón que muestra el input) no se muestre mas, y se guarde en localstorage.
No he encontrado nada al respecto, pero hice lo siguiente:

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Estrellas</a> // Abre un modal con estrellas  

<p class="clasificacion">
    <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="1">
    <label for="radio1">★</label>
    <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="2">
    <label for="radio2">★</label>
    <input id="radio3" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="3">
    <label for="radio3">★</label>
    <input id="radio4" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="4">
    <label for="radio4">★</label>
    <input id="radio5" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="5">
    <label for="radio5">★</label>
  </p>
```

Entonces, al hacer clic en cualquier estrella, automaticamente deje de mostrarse el boton que dice "Estrellas"

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir algún fragmento de código con las cosas que has intentado hasta ahora?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para solucionar este caso realicé lo siguiente:

1. Agregar un id al botón "estrellas" para poder saber cual es el botón que tengo que ocular
2. Importar un archivo js en el que ejecutaría el código para "ocultar" el botón en caso dado seleccionen la calificación.
   Esos 2 pasos se traducirían en el siguiente código:

```html
    <body>
        <a id="startButton" class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Estrellas</a> // Abre un modal con estrellas  
    
    <p class="clasificacion">
        <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="1">
        <label for="radio1">★</label>
        <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="2">
        <label for="radio2">★</label>
        <input id="radio3" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="3">
        <label for="radio3">★</label>
        <input id="radio4" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="4">
        <label for="radio4">★</label>
        <input id="radio5" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="5">
        <label for="radio5">★</label>
      </p>
        
    </body>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
```

Y el archivo js contendría lo siguiente:

```js
let calificadores = document.getElementsByName("estrellas")
let estrellasButton = document.getElementById("startButton")
//con esto evaluas de que cuando recarguen la pagina el boton siga oculto
if(localStorage.getItem("calificacion")){
    estrellasButton.style.display = "none";
}
//con esto ocultas el boton y guardas el localstorage
let seleccionarCalificacion = function() {
    let calificacion = this.getAttribute("value");
    localStorage.setItem('calificacion', calificacion);
    estrellasButton.style.display = "none";
};
for (let i = 0; i < calificadores.length; i++) {
    calificadores[i].addEventListener('click', seleccionarCalificacion,false);
}
```

**EDIT: para solo ocultar cuando la calificación sea mínimo 3**

```js
let calificadores = document.getElementsByName("estrellas")
let mostrarUOcultar = function(){
    let estrellasButton = document.getElementById("startButton")
    let calificacionGuardada = localStorage.getItem("calificacion")
    if(calificacionGuardada>2){
        estrellasButton.style.display = "none";
    }else{
        estrellasButton.style.display = "block";
    }
}    
let seleccionarCalificacion = function() {
    let calificacion = this.getAttribute("value");
    localStorage.setItem('calificacion', calificacion);
    mostrarUOcultar()
};
for (let i = 0; i < calificadores.length; i++) {
    calificadores[i].addEventListener('click', seleccionarCalificacion,false);
}
mostrarUOcultar()
```

Comment: Saludos y gracias. Lo agregué. Pero al hacer clic en una estrella, y recargar la web sigue apareciendo el boton.

Comment: Ya se cual es el problema. El boton ese que tiene el id, está en otra pagina. Al hacer clic, abre un modal, que tiene un iframe del formulario con las estrellas. Como se podría hacer

Comment: Justo iba a comentarte acerca de eso, el código lo probé en mi computador y funcionó, pero no se que otros elementos puedas tener tu que ocasionen otro comportamiento.  Si quieres puedes comentarme que mas te pasa, pero si te funcionó me ayudaría si marcas como la respuesta como solución :)

Comment: Gracias, si funciona, lo que hice fue agrupar todo en un archivo, y a su vez, lo muestro en un InnerHTML, y ahora si va perfecto.

Comment: Perfecto, me alegra que te funcionara.

Comment: No se si se puede agregar algo mas, que no pude, y es que si calificación es igual o menor a 2, este boton se siga mostrando. Se puede?

Comment: @MatiST00 Claro, en primer lugar solo sería colocar una validación de que si la calificación es menor o igual a 2 entonces no lo oculte. El resultado sería el que está en mi respuesta ahora que la edite.